Why is the installed Visual Studio Code application closing abruptly while tying to run it?
I had just successfully installed the MS Visual Studio code preparatory to my Hyperledger composer installation (code_1.92.0-1722473020_amd64(1).deb) for my Oracle VMWare - based Ubuntu 24.04 LTS following the guideline in the link text from the beginning to the end.
However, after running the command "code", an error message was seen that made me inquisitive about the bug as seen in the image attached.
How does one fix this issue?

I had tried to troubleshoot by restarting the Virtual Machine being used, in addition to starting the process afresh.
